# Proving that induction works for von Neuman's construction of naturals

Tags: elementary-number-theory, foundations, peano-axioms

I have read on a number of books and other references that the von Neumann ordinals -- the model for ${\mathbb N}$  in which zero is $\emptyset$ and $s(n)=n\cup\{n\}$ -- satisfy all Peano axioms. I can work out the proofs for axioms 1-4, but how would I prove that the induction axiom works on such construction without using induction itself?
Is it OK to use induction, since it's metalanguage anyway?

Comment: You need a complete def'n of "ordinal" to begin.  And then a def'n of "finite ordinal". It would be better from a foundational viewpoint if these were without the Axioms of Infinity, Choice, and Foundation (Regularity). The usual def'n of $x\in$ On is that (i) $x$ is a transitive set , i.e. $\forall y\in x\;(y\subset x)$ , and (ii) $ x$ is well-ordered by $\in .$ There are several  ways to define finite ordinal, e.g. $x\in$ On and $x$ is well-ordered by $\in^*,$  where $y\in^*z$  iff $ z\in y,$.... or $x\in$ On and $\forall y\in x\cup \{x\}\;(y=\cup y\implies y=\phi.)$

Comment: What is I take it, as I have also seen, as "a construction of the natural numbers". Some set theory books just define them and claim that they have the properties defined by Peano/Dedekind...

Comment: Induction on $\mathbb N$ is equivalent to the well-ordering principle: If some $n\in \mathbb N$ has property $P(n),$ then there is a least such $n.$  In set theory if some ordinal  $n$ has property $P(n)$ then the set $\{x\in  n\cup \{n\}: P(x)\}$ exists and is a non-empty subset of the ordinal $n+1=n\cup \{n\},$ so it has a $\in$-least member $m.$  Then $m$ must be least of all of the ordinals that have property $P.$

Comment: But then I'd be using something equivalent to the induction principle to prove the fifth axiom... So I suppose I cannot actually prove that the numbers as constructed by von Neumann behave as prescribed by Peano's axiom (V)? (At least not too easily, I guess)?

Comment: The trouble with writing $s(n)=n\cup \{n\}$ is in not specifying which  $n$ are to be included or excluded in order to define   the finite ordinals ... The  def'n of the finite ordinals implies , as in my prior comment, that they are a model for the Peano axiom of induction.

Comment: I have been told here IIUC that the ZF axiom of infinity is equivalent to assuming the existence of a Dedekind-infinite set. From such a set, you can select at least one subset that can be easily shown to satisfy Peano's Axioms. Then you won't have to mess around with von Neumann ordinals.